# Exclude Mysql column upon request when printing a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form which the user chooses how to view a table of running results

IE slowest time first etc

I need to give the user the option whether they want to view the runners age or not.

If the user chooses not to the form will send 0. I know its not the best-looking code but I was simply trying to make it select all of the columns if age is required and all columns except Age if age is not required

thanks for any help.

```
$value = $_POST['SortBy'];
$sortOption = $_POST['SortIn'];
$ageReq = $_POST['IncludeAgeGrade'];
echo $ageReq;
//sorting the database to userinput
if ( $ageReq == false)
{
    $query = "SELECT RunnerID, EventID, Date, FinishTime,Position,CategoryID,PB FROM Results ORDER BY $value $sortOption";
} else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Results ORDER BY $value $sortOption ";
}
```

Comment: when i choose that I do not want the age results it will still give the same table as if i did want the age

Comment: Why just NOT display the age when displaying the form? Also, what does the `echo $ageReq;` show?

Comment: The user specifies how to order the table and whether or not the want to see the ages, Sorry i was using that echo $ageReq; to see what the form was sending and it was 1 for yes and 0 for no

Comment: I thiink that my issue is in the first query line as it is being called its just not ignoring the age column